# How can I use encoded text in if statement?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

[PROBLEM]
How can I use encoded text in if statement ?
Even if the vars (serialNumberValue  + encodedValue) have the same type, the following happy flow code will not get executed.

[CURRENT OUTPUT]
happy flow code will not get executed.

[DESIRED OUTPUT]
happy flow code should get executed.

[CODE]

```
# Initiliaze secure window
import wx 
secureApp = wx.App(False) 
topSecure = wx.Frame(None, title=" test - Enter serial number",  style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
topSecure.Center()
topSecure.SetBackgroundColour('LIGHTGREY')
topSecure.SetSize(360,150)





def validateSerialNumber(event):
    print "test"
    serialNumberValue = serialNumber.GetValue()
    print "serialNumberValue is: ", serialNumberValue
    import platform
    print platform.node()
    encodedValue = platform.node().encode("base64")
    print "encodedValue type is: " , type (encodedValue), encodedValue
    print "serialNumberValue type is: " , type (str(serialNumberValue)), serialNumberValue
    if (str(serialNumberValue)) == encodedValue:
        print "ok"
        topSecure.Destroy()
    else:
        print "not ok"
        import wx
        dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Serial number invalid.', 'test - serial number', wx.OK)
        dial.ShowModal()


sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
# Add serial number label
serialLabel = wx.StaticText( topSecure, wx.ID_ANY, "Enter serial number:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0, )
sizer.Add(serialLabel,(1,2),(1,2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM, border=1)
# Add serial number textbox
serialNumber = wx.TextCtrl(topSecure, -1, "", size=(175, -1))
sizer.Add(serialNumber,(2,2),(2,14),wx.EXPAND)
# Add ok button    
okButton = wx.Button(topSecure, -1, "OK", (160,100), size=(45, -1))
sizer.Add(okButton,(5,12),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)
topSecure.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, validateSerialNumber, okButton)
topSecure.SetSizer(sizer)
topSecure.SetFocus()
topSecure.Center()
topSecure.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
secureApp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Do you get an error: please show the output of your program

Comment: hi. i get no error but the code goes only through "else" branch, even if str(serialNumberValue)) and encodedValue vars have: the same value, the same type (str), I will dig some more....

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the problem here but you are encoding `platform.node()` and not the input, shouldn't the if statement read:

```
if (str(serialNumberValue.encode("base64"))) == encodedValue:
    print "ok"
    topSecure.Destroy()
```